# How can I have a Table Cell to perform two different segues but with conditions?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new to iOS Development so please forgive me for asking silly questions or performing silly actions.

So now, here's the problem. I am developing an app, I have a tab bar controller as the initial, called [Initial Tab View]. One of the tab is a table view that displaying all the items, lets call this [Item View]. Once the user tap on the cell, it will push to another view and show the details, the [Detail View]. Another tab is also a table view but with static cells, [Static View], which I use it to select an item and return.

For a clearer picture: If I access the [Item View] from the initial tab view, just simply follow [Initial Tab View]->[Item View]->[Detail View]. However, if I access the [Static View] first and then go to the [Item View], the procedure will be like [Initial Tab View]->[Static View]->[Item View]->[Static View].

I have no idea how to implement the second one (with the [Static View] one) in [Item View], can anyone help? Or there is another better approach? Many thanks.

```
// Code from [Item View]

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *identifier = @"CustomShopCell";
ShopCustomTableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[ShopCustomTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                                      reuseIdentifier:identifier];
}

if (searchResult != nil) {
    //cell.textLabel.text = [searchResult objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    Shop *shop = searchResult[indexPath.row];
    if ([shop.shopNameChi length] == 0) {
        cell.lblName.text = shop.shopName;
    } else {
        cell.lblName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ | %@", shop.shopName, shop.shopNameChi];
    }
    cell.lblLocation.text = shop.unit;
    cell.imgImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    cell.imgImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:shop.imageData];

} else {
    //cell.textLabel.text = [list objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    Shop *shop = shopList[indexPath.row];
    if ([shop.shopNameChi length] == 0) {
        cell.lblName.text = shop.shopName;
    } else {
        cell.lblName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ | %@", shop.shopName, shop.shopNameChi];
    }
    cell.lblLocation.text = shop.unit;
    cell.imgImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    cell.imgImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:shop.imageData];

}

return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if(![self isKindOfClass:[NavigationMainTableViewController class]]){
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showShopDetail" sender:self];
    }
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Show us your tableview methods (cellforrow & didselect), and maybe your data loading methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do (if i'm sure i understood what you're doing) is create two segue links with differnt identifiers (with a clear name, I like this formatting "fromHereToThere"). Then in your didselect you can just call your segue with an if statement, like so :

```
if (your condition){

 [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"fromHomeToStatic" sender:self];

}else{

 [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"fromHomeToDetail" sender:self];

}
```

Then in your `prepareForSegue` method (the one in comment by default in every controller class) you can choose what data to pass along, with

```
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"fromHomeToDetail"])
{
  //Manage your usual stuff here for the detail identifier
  //Ask me again if you need extra help with that
}

if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"fromHomeToStatic"]){

 //Manage here for the static identifier
}
```

But i'm not really exactly sure what you meant with your question so i might be completly off topic :D

EDIT : Okay apparently you wanna know where you're coming FROM when you're loading your third controller. So here is a way to do that.

In your destination controller, add this in .h

```
@property (nonatomic) BOOL fromStatic;
```

(or whatever you want really)

Then in your origin controller, in the `prepareForSegue`, if  you're coming from Static, set the `BOOL` of the next controller to `YES`, if not, set it to `NO`, like this

```
DetailViewController *dvc = segue.destionationViewController;
dvc.fromStatic = YES;  //if you're writing this from the static controller
```

In the viewDidLoad of the destination controller just check if it's YES or NO and react accordingly.

Am I getting this right or am I still confused with your problem? I'm still not completly sure what you're asking haha :D

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have been using your commands, but I am not able to come up with the condition. The condition should be [Which view is the pushing to the current view]. How can I distinguish the previous views, [Initial Tab View] and [Static View], and code it?

Comment: The initial views come from the same controller class in both cases?

Comment: I am not so sure about your question. All the views mentioned has it own .h and .m. Is it what you are asking? Thanks

Comment: If they come from different classes, you can simply check like this :

`if([self isKindOfClass:[InitialViewController class]]){ ... }else{ ...}`

Comment: Yhea its pretty much what i'm asking. a view is just an element, a controller "manages" many views. (explained very roughly :p)

Comment: actually show me your code it's gonna be simpler :D your tableview methods

Comment: code uploaded. However, it seems that your suggestion is not working. Hope you can help me with the code :P Thanks again.

Comment: My solution can't actually work. You have two table views in the same controller ? If yes, you can Check for equality in the didSelect method. If tableView == yourTableView, perform segue, else, perform the other segue.  Am i clear?

Comment: I think you might misunderstood my problem. I can perform segues but I am actually looking for solution that how can I know the [Item View] is either pushed by [Initial Tab View] or by [Static View]. In [Item View], I have to perform two different segues based on the previous view. The segues are both come from the table cell of [Item View]. Is this clearer? Thanks for helping me though

Comment: Oh.
Well i guess i'll edit my answer. :D Check here in a minute

Comment: The thing that's confusing me is, you're saying you have different views (so i'm guessing you mean "controllers"), but they come from the same tableview? Or do they come from DIFFERENT tableviews in different controllers? If i'm finally understanding this, then my EDIT should help you. Just add a boolean property in your destination, and set it to YES (for example) if you come from X, and to NO if you come from Y. Then in that controller check that boolean and you'll know where you come from ! (if it's YES, you're coming from X, else, from Y !)

Comment: Yes! This sounds work. You got my point. But I still have one more question. How to pass the boolean value from the Tab Bar Controller? I designed the application like this: [Tab Bar Controller] -> [Navigation Controller] -> [Table View Controller]. How can I pass the value from start to end? Or is it a bad design and I should make changes? Thanks again, you really help me a lot. :D

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this one. You can set that method for each cell you taping.

```
   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"yourIdentifierHere" sender:self];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Static Cell Prototype . Just drag from cell to the view which you want to push and select push in segue . If you are using dynamic UITableViewCell. You can performSegue in didSelectRowAtIndex Method .